# How to install an old version of Firefox side-by-side to default version without conflicts?

Tags: firefox

I have a new version of Firefox (46).

I need to install Firefox 44 to find a bug, that appears in a web app I am writing, but only in version 44 and older.

How do I do that? I don't want to have any conflicts, I don't want the older version to overwrite the current settings, etc.

Comment: Safest bet would be a virtual machine.

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 6):

You have three options.

1. Use a portable version of firefox.

You can check the link for details: [Using portable firefox and fixing flash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73123/portable-firefox-linux)

2. Use Virtual machine and use firefox therein.
3. Install two versions of firefox. (Probably this is what you are looking for.)

Download the older version of firefox from the archive: [Mozilla.org_ftp_site](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

Unzip to a path.

Next open terminal and use the following command to add a new firefox user.

`firefox --no-remote -P`

Create a new user, take note of the user-name.

Next, create a launcher for the 'firefox' you just unzip. Go inside the unzipped folder , there you will find a firefox file (probably binary) which launches the program. 
When creating the launcher, update the command as:

`/path/to/unzipped/firefox --no-remote -P "<user-name>"`

[Creating launcher in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

And now, when you will use this launcher then older firefox (which you want to use for testing) will open. Important - check the build version to verify.

In the url bar ->     `about:`

(Your newer version of firefox will not be affected, and it has `firefox --no-remote -P "default"` as command.)

Comment: Like you write it now, you will start the same Firefox (you'll need a path to the new Firefox!).  Make sure you actually start the right version…  Also, it's probably better to use `--no-remote` (double dash) as documented  in `firefox --help` (the manpage is clearly outdated).

Comment: And: a third option is to use a VM, of course.

Comment: I think the problem is that the .Mozilla directory is shared.  I created a standalone unzip gz downloaded file.  It is not really "portable". What I need to do is have its own Mozilla directory (not the one in the home directory)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new Firefox user profile
and install by the -no-remote command line
Please visit:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/974208

Comment: I did creat a new profile.  It prompted me for it.  I called the profile firefox54